# Install linux to hard drive from live partition

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, live-environment

I was thinking that I could make a small 4GB partition on my 320GB hard drive. This small partition could be used as a live install partition. What i would do is I would make the partition, boot from it, then use the boted live isntall to install ubuntu to a different partition. then I would boot from the newly created partition and change the live install to a different live install. then i would boot from the new install and install to another partition. then i would do the same 1 or 2 more times. Dont ask me why I want to install the 3 or 4 different derivatives instead of just installing multiple desktop environments on one install. I just do.

Thanks, Ashton.

Comment: So... No one knows how to do this? Darn...

Comment: Your question has only been here for an hour.  Have patience, and wait for answers.

Answer (score 0):

I do that but have ISO on another drive. Not sure if your partition is in extended partition if you can unmount during install (it asks but do not know if it really works.

I just copy ISO to partition in a /ISO folder and use grub2's loop mount feature to directly boot the ISO.

This will boot an ISO from a hard drive.

ISO Booting with Grub 2 from Hard drive

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Examples - you may copy & edit for your path & ISO version

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples